# Does the Tyrolean crossing (zip line) from Tyrol?

Tags: history, sport

I have heard some people claim that the Tyrolean crossing is named after the Tyrol region in Austria, but I cannot find any reference to it.

Is this practice from Tyrol?

Comment: wiki says yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-line

Comment: @Zenon-does WIki have a decent reference in footnotes? If so, make that and answer and you're done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread below is the only mention of the people first responsible for the traverse. This is credited as [Tita Piaz](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tita_Piaz) and [Hans Dülfer](http://Hans%20D%C3%BClfer) (although due to the lack of quantity of information there may have been others involved).

Of note is this translation of the wikipedia article on Tita Piaz:

> It is also popular with climbers for
>   inventing the technique of 
>   rappelling . Today his technique,
>   which went into disuse with the advent
>   of harnesses and modern belay devices
>   , is known simply as "Piaz method" or
>   "Dulfer-Piaz" (also the mountaineer
>   Hans Dulfer is considered the inventor
>   of this technique).

And this one from the Hans Dülfer wikipedia page:

> In addition to success in climbing,
>   layback was very important for the
>   technical innovations introduced. The
>   best known are the techniques of
>   abseiling that still bears his name,
>   Dülfersitz, [3](http://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jl1RVN79N-EC&oi=fnd&pg=PP8&dq=%22Hans%20D%C3%BClfer%22&ots=J8Xen5dfaI&sig=Fqz9Fjg_bPLGpA-Z2vtdEhlMo4g#v=onepage&q=hans&f=false) and the technique for
>   ascending layback cracks in the rock.

Also of note is this mention in [Pilgrims of the Vertical](http://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jl1RVN79N-EC&oi=fnd&pg=PP8&dq=%22Hans%20D%C3%BClfer%22&ots=J8Xen5dfaI&sig=Fqz9Fjg_bPLGpA-Z2vtdEhlMo4g#v=onepage&q=hans&f=false):

> ...and by 1900 Hans Dülfer, Otto
>   Herzog, and Hans Fiechtl had refined
>   and systematized aid climbing. They
>   forged harder pitons for the thinner
>   cracks, steel snap-links (carabiners)
>   to connect pitons to the rope, and
>   rope ladders (etriers) to attach to
>   pitons. but the values inscribed in
>   their climbs and writings had already
>   reshaped the sport.They also created
>   new techniques such as a body belay to
>   hold falls, a way to wrap the rope
>   around a body and rap- pel downward,
>   and a method of penduluming.

[Thread: History of the Tyrolean Traverse:](http://www.supertopo.com/climbing/thread.php?topic_id=484041&tn=0)

> Piaz and Duelfer were contemporaries--
>   Piaz claims to have done the first,
>   but I doubt that we could definitively
>   credit one or the other at this point.
>   There's no doubt that it was part of
>   the technical innovation to come out
>   of the Dolomites and the Kaisergebrige
>   in the Tirolian Alps. Pitons,
>   rappelling, tension traverses, aid
>   climbing, stirrups, pendulums, and the
>   Tirolian traverse were all developed
>   by Bavarian, Tirolian and South
>   Tirolian climbers in the late 19th and
>   early 20th century.

http://ezra.cornell.edu/posting.php?timestamp=1302159600

> “‘Tyro’ is short for Tyrolean
>   Traverse, a climbing system using
>   ropes to horizontally cross a barrier
>   such as a raging river, a crevasse,
>   or, in this case, one of Cornell’s
>   famous gorges.  It was first developed
>   by climbers in the eastern Alps of
>   Austria/Italy, in a region called
>   Tirol.  Think of it as a practical zip
>   line, where the goal is not to go
>   fast, but to simply to cross an
>   otherwise impassible barrier.”

[History of the zipline](http://knol.google.com/k/history-of-the-zipline#):

> There's no doubt that it was part of
>   the technical innovation to come out
>   of the Dolomites and the Kaisergebrige
>   in the Tirolian Alps. Pitons,
>   rappelling, tension traverses, aid
>   climbing, stirrups, pendulums, and the
>   Tirolian traverse were all developed
>   by Bavarian, Tirolian and South
>   Tirolian climbers in the late 19th and
>   early 20th century.

Comment: thanks, the article is nice but I am looking some reference or investigation made by some credible source like an university.

Comment: @santiagozky - See my updated answer. I don't think you are going to find a university article.

Comment: yes, I've been looking also and haven't find anything more interesting than that. Thanks for taking your time to find the info.